# join and paste command

Tags: join, paste, gnu-coreutils

I have 2 files.

```
bash-3.2$ cat result2.txt 
HOSTNAME=host4 2 
HOSTNAME=host1 2 
HOSTNAME=host6 1 
HOSTNAME=host3 1 
HOSTNAME=host2 1 

bash-3.2$ cat result1.txt 
HOSTNAME=host1 2 
HOSTNAME=host2 1 

bash-3.2$ cat result.txt 
HOSTNAME=host1 2
HOSTNAME=host2 1
HOSTNAME=host3 1

bash-3.2$ cat result3.txt 
HOSTNAME=host4 3
HOSTNAME=host1 4
HOSTNAME=host3 7
HOSTNAME=host2 8
HOSTNAME=host6 6


bash-3.2$ join -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 -a 1 result2.txt result1.txt 
HOSTNAME=host4 2 
HOSTNAME=host1 2 
HOSTNAME=host6 1 
HOSTNAME=host3 1 
HOSTNAME=host2 1
```

I would like to join 2 files when the order and value of 1st column of both the files are not same.

I want the output to be

```
hostname       result  result1 result2 result3
HOSTNAME=host1 2       2         2      4
HOSTNAME=host2 1       1         1      8
HOSTNAME=host3 1       0         1      7
HOSTNAME=host4 0       0         2      3
HOSTNAME=host6 0       0         1      6
```

Even paste command is not working as it assumes the 1st column of both the files are same. Or is there any other command in bash that i can use for this output

Answer (score 4):

## This is a solution on the first requirement, with just two files. For the solution on multiple files, check [hek2mgl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38995319/1983854)!

What about using `awk` for this? It is just a matter of storing the data from the second file (result1.txt) in an array and then printing accordingly when reading the first one (result2.txt):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {data[$1]=$2; next} {print $0, ($1 in data) ? data[$1] : 0}' f2 f1
HOSTNAME=host4 2  0
HOSTNAME=host1 2  2
HOSTNAME=host6 1  0
HOSTNAME=host3 1  0
HOSTNAME=host2 1  1
```

If you need this to be sorted, pipe to `sort`: `awk '...' f2 f1 | sort` or say `awk '...' f2 <(sort f1)`.

#### How does this work?

- `awk 'things' f2 f1`
  reads the file `f2` and then the file `f1`.
- `FNR==NR {data[$1]=$2; next}`
  Since FNR stands for File Number of Record and NR for Number of Record, when reading the first file, these values match. This way, saying `FNR==NR` allows you to do something *just* when reading the first file. Here, it consists in storing the data in an array `data[first field] = second field`. Then, `next` triggers to skip the current line without doing anything else. You can read more about this technique in [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/).
- `{print $0, ($1 in data) ? data[$1] : 0}`
  Now we are reading the second file. Here, we check if the first field is present in the array. If so, we print its corresponding value from the first file; otherwise, we just print a `0`.

Comment: thanks.. what if i have multiple files to be joined into 1 output file..

Comment: @PrMeAsAr then you need to edit your original question providing a [mcve]. To prevent this, you may want to check [ask] and also notice that you can accept an answer if it solves your problem (you haven't done this yet after 8 questions!)

Comment: and also is the order of the files passed to the awk command important
    bash-3.2$ awk 'FNR==NR {data[$1]=$2; next} {print $0, ($1 in data) ? data[$1] : 0}' result2.txt result1.txt 
    HOSTNAME=host1 2 2
    HOSTNAME=host2 1 1

Comment: @PrMeAsAr yes it is, you have to provide `result2.txt` as the second argument, since it is the one used to print the full lines.

Comment: i have 5 files and i do not know the number of records in each file. i need to join all of them based on the hostname and 5 columns each column giving the number mentioned in each file for that particular hostname

Comment: @PrMeAsAr as I said before, you need to edit your question to explain this. Do not fully update until you are sure your question fully conveys your needs, since we are not going to keep updating answers after every update :)

Comment: for eg, result1 may hve host 1, host 2. result2.txt may have host2 , host3 and host4. result3.txt will have host1, host2, host 5, host6. result4.txt will have host 4,host5,host6,host7. the output should hve columns hostname, result1 count,result2 count,result3 count result4 count

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: You changed the question significantly after I've answered it already. Now you say that you have 4 files instead of just 2.

However, the basic logic keeps the same, we just need to join again with the results of the previous join operation:

```
join -o auto -j1 -a1 -a2 -e0  \
    <(join -o auto -j1 -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 \
        <(join -o auto  -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 \
            <(sort r1.txt) <(sort r0.txt)) <(sort r2.txt)) <(sort r3.txt)
```

Output:

```
HOSTNAME=host1 2 2 2 4
HOSTNAME=host2 1 1 1 8
HOSTNAME=host3 0 1 1 7
HOSTNAME=host4 0 0 2 3
HOSTNAME=host6 0 0 1 6
```

---

You are looking for the following command:

```
join -o '1.1 1.2 2.2' -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -e 0  <(sort r2.txt) <(sort r1.txt)
```

Output:

```
HOSTNAME=host1 2 2
HOSTNAME=host2 1 1
HOSTNAME=host3 1 0
HOSTNAME=host4 2 0
HOSTNAME=host6 1 0
```

Explanation:

- `-j 1` is the same as `-1 1 -2 1` (which you had). It means "join by field 1 in both files"
- `-a 1 -a 2` prints un-joinable lines from file1 and file2
- `-e 0` uses `0` as the default value for empty columns
- `<(sort file)` is so called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)
- `-o '1.1 1.2 2.2'` tells `join` that you want to output field 1 from file1 and field2 from file1 and file2. If one of the files is missing field2, a `0` will be used because of `-e 0`.

Comment: Nice! Note though that the requirement [may be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994873/join-and-paste-command#comment65342249_38994951) something more complex involving more files.

Comment: @fedorqui Ah, I see. Imo a join operation can by definition just include 2 result sets. Am I missing something?

Comment: Mmm you can always use process substitution and say `join <(join file1 file2) file3` and so on.

Comment: @fedorqui Yeah that can be done. However the `-o` parameter would need to get changed on every call to `join` - unless `-o auto` can be used.

Comment: thanks so much for the response... but -o auto doesnt work... getting error join: invalid file number in field spec: `auto'

The command used is 

    join -o auto -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -e 0  <(join -o auto -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -e 0  <(join -o auto  -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -e 0  <(sort result.txt) <(sort result1.txt)) <(sort result2.txt)) <(sort result3.txt)

Comment: Make sure that you remove empty space at the end of each line in the files. Then it works

Comment: Btw, that can be achieved using `sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//' file`.

Comment: doesnt work sorry... i removed all the spaces from each line in the file still getting this error

bash-3.2$ join -o auto -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -e 0  <(sort result.txt) <(sort result1.txt)
join: invalid file number in field spec: `auto'

Comment: bash-3.2$ cat result.txt 
HOSTNAME=host1 2
HOSTNAME=host2 1
HOSTNAME=host3 1

bash-3.2$ cat result1.txt 
HOSTNAME=host1 2
HOSTNAME=host2 1

Comment: Please don't post the content of the files in comments. I assume they are the same as in the question - without spaces at the end of the lines (and no extra newlines) . Since you have bash-3.2 I assume that you are running on MaxOS. Can you try to install GNU(!) coreutils?

Comment: im using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 (Tikanga). I cannot install GNU coreutils

Comment: This is pretty ancient. -> update! (or code something custom)

Comment: is there any way to get it working in the env that i have.. i cannot update or install anything. Sorry

Comment: Looks not. But you can always use the programming language of your choice and write a custom program.

Comment: im using a loop in a script to using the join command.. A strange issue im seeing is the join command is working fine in the terminal but same command called within the script is failing. the command im using is join -o '1.1 1.2 2.2' -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -e 0  <(sort r2.txt) <(sort r1.txt) > output.txt

Comment: the redirecting of the output to output.txt is failing in the script but works fine when i run from terminal

Comment: Are you running the script with `bash script.sh`? I mean `bash`, not `sh`

Comment: im running it as sh test.sh

Comment: @hek2mgl.. Is it possible to replace -o auto with column numbers. in nested join command that you have suggested... i have 5 txt (which is fixed) that i need to join.